# Using awk how do I print all lines containing duplicates of specific columns?

Tags: awk, printing, duplicates, find, multiple-columns

Input:

```
a;3;c;1
a;4;b;2
a;5;c;1
```

Output:

```
a;3;c;1
a;5;c;1
```

Hence, all lines which have duplicates of columns 1,3 and 4 should be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a 2-pass approach is OK:

```
$ awk -F';' '{key=$1 FS $3 FS $4} NR==FNR{cnt[key]++;next} cnt[key]>1' file file
a;3;c;1
a;5;c;1
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk -F';' '
    { key=$1 FS $3 FS $4; a[key,++cnt[key]]=$0 }
    END {
        for (key in cnt)
            if (cnt[key] > 1)
                for (i=1; i<=cnt[key]; i++)
                    print a[key,i]
    }
' file
a;3;c;1
a;5;c;1
```

The output order of keys in that second script will be random due to the `in` operator - easily fixed if that's an issue.

Comment: when I read my answer again..... I think to have that idea, I must have drunk too much coffee.... thx +1

Answer (score 2):

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -F';' '{k=$1 FS $3 FS $4}
    NR==FNR{if(a[k]){p[a[k]];p[NR]}a[k]=NR;next}FNR in p' file file
```

It goes through the file twice, first time, it marked the line numbers should be printed, second time print those lines.

Comment: Thanks for quick and excellent answers!
Is it possible to pipe the output from a command, for example curl, into your one-liner, instead of providing a filename twice?

Comment: yes, @Markus you can save all lines in an awk array, if the input is not huge.

Comment: @Kent I think you may have been missing a cup of coffee before posting that :-). See my first script at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43681155/1745001 for how simple it should be with a 2-pass approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=";" }NR==1{ split($0, a, ";"); print }NR>1{ if ( a[1] == $1 && a[3] == $3 && a[4] == $4){ print }}'
```

Output:

```
a;3;c;1
a;5;c;1
```

Works of course only if the line with specific column is the first one.

Comment: what if the duplicated line doesn't sit on first line?

Comment: Yeah I know. Wrote it in the post.

Comment: No, what if line 1 and 3 are duplicated and line 2 and line 20 are duplicated too but with different 1, 3,4 combination? your answer is in general not the solution to OP's problem

Comment: I see the problem. Haven't thought about that. Just read OP's question and tried to solve it. And I admit that your solution is the general one.