# Using awk how to to merge lines which are duplicates based on multiple columns and substitute the average for another column

Tags: awk, duplicates, multiple-columns, substitution

This is a variant on 
[Using awk how do I print all lines containing duplicates of specific columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675831/using-awk-how-do-i-print-all-lines-containing-duplicates-of-specific-columns)

Input:

```
a;3;c;1
a;6;b;2
a;5;c;1
```

Output:

```
a;4;c;1
a;6;b;2
```

Hence, all lines which have duplicates of columns 1,3 and 4 should be merged to one line and printing the average of column 2 in 
column 2. All the lines which don't have duplicates (according to columns 1,3 and 4) should be printed as they are.

Comment: so, what have tried to do this?

Comment: So, what's the rule for merge data?

Comment: Come on, you've asked and received answers to multiple questions, you must've learned **something** by now - let's see an attempt!

Comment: Attempt to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one liner a try:

```
awk -F';' '{k=$1 FS $3 FS $4;t[k]++;a[k]=($2+a[k])/t[k]}
          END{for(x in a){sub(FS,FS a[x]"&",x);print x}}' file
```

- it first calculates the average and save in the value of a hashtable
- after all lines were processed, just insert the calculated result into the 2nd field position.
- Note that the order of  lines in output may be different from the input.

Answer (score 3):

***gawk*** approach:

```
awk -F";" '{a[$1,$3,$4]+=$2; ++c[$1,$3,$4]}END{OFS=";"; for(i in a){ 
     split(i, sep, SUBSEP); print sep[1],a[i]/c[i],sep[2],sep[3]}}' file
```

The output:

```
a;6;b;2
a;4;c;1
```

---

`a[$1,$3,$4]+=$2;` - group lines by the same 1st, 3rd and 4th field, accumulating the 2nd field vale

`++c[$1,$3,$4]` - count the number of grouped records

`split(i, sep, SUBSEP);` - split compound key into array containing 1st, 3rd and 4th field value

Answer (score 1):

an indirect approach

```
swap12() { awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {t=$1;$1=$2;$2=t}1' "$1";} 
swap12 file | 
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} 
           {k=$2 FS $3 FS $4; a[k]+=$1; c[k]++} 
     END   {for(k in a) print a[k]/c[k],k}' | 
swap12
```